# How to check Salesforce's API Usage from Talend

Tags: salesforce, talend

I'm trying to read the API usage, there's a way to do it from the Salesforce console (Setup->Company Information->API Request Usage), I'd like to know how to do it by Talend.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this is not possible as this information is not provided by any salesforce API.
The only way should be to scrape the page where the information is supposed to be displayed (but don't know if it is still possible).